# Reseed identity increments SQL Server C# row_number() DENSE_RANK()

Tags: c#, sql-server, max, row-number, dense-rank

I am trying to insert using a stored procedure into a table where I have two primary key columns `AgencyID` and `ModelID` (`int` auto). The condition is that as long as the `AgencyID` does not change, the `ModelID` column will be incremented by 1 automatically.

So far no issues, but I need to reseed the `ModelID` back to 1 once the user changes the `AgencyID`.

Like this:

```
AgencyID  ModelID
-----------------
 AB        1
 AB        2
 AB        3
 CD        1
 CD        2
 EG        1
 EG        2
 AB        4
```

This is my insert stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spModel_insert]
     (@AgencyID varchar(10),
      @ModelName varchar(100),
      @Gender bit,
      @Email varchar(100),
      @Address varchar(250),
      @ImageURL varchar(250),
      @ModelID int output)
AS
    INSERT INTO ModelsT (AgencyID, ModelName, Gender, Email, [Address], ImageURL)
    VALUES (@AgencyID, @ModelName,  @Gender, @Email, @Address, @ImageURL)

    SET @ModelID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I could solve it through twisted ways in C# by using select Max Modelid through `ExecuteScalar` into a variable and add 1 in the filtered SQL, and `dataBindingSource.Count` for the first record:

```
int x;
x = ModelBindingSource.Count;\\ This code is inside the Add button.

if (x <= 1)
{
    txt_ModelID.Text = x.ToString();   
}
else if (x > 1)
{
    GetModelID(); // This is the max select SQL method where other variables 
    //will +1 to set it in the txt_ModelID.Text.
}
```

But the above means that the `ModelID` will not be auto in the stored procedure while it is needed to be auto. Also I don't find this really practical since I am trying to keep all my logic separated focusing on the stored procedures.

I know it can be done through `row_number()` or `dense_rank()` but not sure how to use it in the insert stored procedure? Please note that in case of deletion the `ModelID` must not be reused and the sequence must continue.

Any help?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks marc, but that's not what i am looking for. varchar or nvarchar or the name of sp_ is not what i am looking for and i agree on all what you said-this is just a sample table i took it quickly as not to disturb the original database. No sure why you understood thats my problem??? my problem I explained well as i believe in the first paragraph.

Comment: And I just fixed the datatype and stored procedure name above as not to create confusion for any one else who would like to help :)